# Android: ListView bug

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list view which has a Textview and an image. When I click on the textview a hidden layout will be expanded for that particular row. But what happening was, for eg., when I click on 2nd row, 10th row is also getting expanded. Here is my code,

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
        holder.mDeleteImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);
        holder.deleteMainRL = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmdeleteMainRL);
        holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);
        holder.mName.setTag(position);
        holder.deleteMainRL.setTag(position);
        final View clickView = convertView;

        holder.mName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout displayAddInfo = (RelativeLayout)clickView.findViewById(R.id.displayRecordRL);
                Animation expandAnim = expand(displayAddInfo,
                                true);
                displayAddInfo
                        .startAnimation(expandAnim);
                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

How can I fix this? Any kind of help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hmFieldMainRL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_shape" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hmFieldName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/displayRecordRL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/no_data"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#F2F2F2" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayRecordRL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/hmFieldName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/display_record_bg"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/displayRecordUpdate"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordPwd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/displayRecordName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/displayRecordShow"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordAddInfoImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/displayRecordPwd"
            android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:src="@drawable/info" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordAddInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/displayRecordAddInfoImg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:hint="Additional Information"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordUpdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/display_record_img"
            android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/update_rec" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordShow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/displayRecordUpdate"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/eye" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/displayRecordShowRed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/displayRecordUpdate"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/redeye"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Provide code of `expand` method. Also change many of `onClickListener`s to one `onItemClickListener` for ListView. Also you have to call `setHasTransientState(true)` before you start animation on a listview item and `setHasTransientState(false)` at the end of the animation (you have to add animation listener). But `setHasTransientState()` was added in API 16.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my application supports from API 9.

Comment: Do you have to scroll to see row 10?

Comment: Ya Im scrolling down to see the 10th row.

Comment: Then I can only guess that `expand()` makes part of a row's layout visible which you need to hide again because every row is recycled as you scroll. Please ask if you need help understanding or doing this. (Also reply to a specific user with `@Sam`, this sends us a notification, otherwise we might never know you replied.)

Comment: @Sam Ya sometimes when I scroll down it expands, I guess the issue is with `clickView` as it is used by other rows. I found that we should maintain states off all items and compare it while setting the `holder`, see the first answer. It'd be grateful if you can help me out with this issue.

Comment: Sure, I'll need a little more information first. Can you post your row's layout in your question? (Click "[edit]" below the question itself.)

Comment: @Sam I added row's layout. Please see the updated part.

Comment: I created a simple project that also has this issue: http://sendfile.pl/280961/ListQuestion.zip
Even if list is short and has no scrolling, when you tap on second item from top (it should change it's background color to blue), it changes background of incorrect item (in this case - second from bottom). I have no idea what happens with this views, it's probably because of calling notifyDatasetChanget().

Comment: @Sam I tested you project, it has no issues. Background color of rows are changing appropriately, the issue you mentioned in ur comment is not happening. But anyway this is simple listview rite, this wud b the same case with custom listview also? If yes, please suggest me to fix this.

Comment: I posted an answer for you, hope it helps. Also that project was posted by a different user.

Comment: @Srujan Simha it does, but it seems that not on android 4.0. I tested it only on 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what happening was, for eg., when I click on 2nd row, 10th row is also getting expanded.

You are fighting the way ListViews recycle the row layouts. But this is easy enough to deal with, first let's add a couple new class variables:

```
SparseBooleanArray expanded = new SparseBooleanArray();
LayoutInflater inflater; // initialize this in your constructor
```

Now we'll use `expanded` to check whether `displayRecordRL` should be visible:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dataFields = items.get(position);
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
        holder.mDeleteImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);
        holder.deleteMainRL = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.hmdeleteMainRL);

        // Add this to your holder
        holder.mAddInfo = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.displayRecordRL);

        holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);
        holder.mName.setTag(position);
        holder.deleteMainRL.setTag(position);

        holder.mName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get the ViewHolder
                holder = (ViewHolder) ((View) v.getParent()).getTag(); 
                Animation expandAnim = expand(holder.mAddInfo, true);
                holder.mAddInfo.startAnimation(expandAnim);

                // Remember that this View is expanded
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                expanded.put(pos, true);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());
    if(expanded.get(position, false)) 
        holder2.mAddInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder2.mAddInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return convertView;
}
```

Notice how this tracks whether each row should be visible and uses a simple if statement to make sure the recycled layout correctly shows or hide the "Add Info" section.

Comment: Great ! It worked. But when I scroll down the data in the EditText is vanishing. I guess its because of the last `if` condition in your code. Any idea to fix it??

Comment: You'll need to store the data in each EditText somewhere and use it like `expanded`. Maybe you can added a new member to DataField or use an `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll work on that, you actually solved most of the problem. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! This Google I/O talk: [Turbo-Charge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) is by one of Android's lead programmers, it will help explain what's happening and why if you still have some questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a attribute to your adapter, a simple `int`. When you click on an item, update the current selected position. When you build the view, check if position equals the selected position.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if(this.selectedPosition == position){
     //add a holder
     else{
     //don't add a holder

     return convertview;
}
```

What I'm saying is that you are encountering a View recycling problem. If you modify item n°2 and then the view of item n°10 is build from the View n°2, you end up with an item unwanted (that will look as it was clicked).

When an item of your list is clicked:

1) update the selected item (attribute of your adapter). Example, if you click on item 12 of your listview, selectedItem = 12;

2) call method notifyDataSetChanged(). This will refresh the view of the list.

3) When you build the view (getView() of adapter), check for each position if it corresponds to the selected item. If it does, build your special view (I don't know exactly what you want to do). If it doesn't correspond to the selected item, build your view "normally"

Comment: you mean I should add `convertView.setTag(holder);` in `if` condition and `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` in `else` part?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the R.id.displayRecordRL as part of the viewholder and on the OnClick method call it.

```
holder.displayAddInfo = (RelativeLayout)clickView.findViewById(R.id.displayRecordRL);
```

and on the OnclickMethod :

```
Animation expandAnim = expand(holder.displayAddInfo,
                                true);
                holder.displayAddInfo
                        .startAnimation(expandAnim);
                    }
```

Comment: I don't find any difference, because if you add the RelativeLayout inside ViewHolder class and set it outside the TextView onclicklistener as "`clickView.findViewById`", it will not be recognised inside the onclick method and that expansion animation never happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you experience could be that you animate a View (converView) that is being re-used for another item in your list-view when scrolling.

Look at this YouTube video and you may get an idea on how to solve your problem.
Chet Haase (Google engineer) "DevBytes" series "ListView Animations" :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs#!